# How to change an environment in its body

Tags: macros, environments, renewcommand

I have the below code.

```
    \documentclass{article}
        \newcounter{ex}
        \newenvironment{ex}{%
            \par\noindent\refstepcounter{ex}{\bfseries Ex \theex.\, }
            }{}
        \newcommand{\Immi}[1]{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
                #1
        \end{minipage}}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{ex}
          Contents 1.
        \end{ex}
        
        \begin{ex}
        \Immi{Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2Contents 2 Contents 2 Contents 2}
        \end{ex}
        
        \Immi{
        \begin{ex}
        Contents 3 Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3Contents 3
\end{ex}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In result complite, the **Ex2** have a newline. It should be like the **Ex 3**.
However, the command `\Immi` must be in body of `ex` environment to manage by a software.
Please help me correct the `\Immi` command or the `ex` environment code.
Thank you in advance.

Update 29/4/2022.
Thankyou for **Mr @pascal978**'s help.

Form his/her code, I modify to below code.
It works for me!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent=0pt
\newcounter{ex}
\newlength{\decal}
\newcommand{\titreexo}{\parbox[t]{\decal}{\bfseries Ex \theex.}%
}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newenvironment{ex}{%
\settowidth{\decal}{\bfseries Ex \theex..}
\par\refstepcounter{ex}{\titreexo}%
}{\vspace{1ex}}

\newlength{\lgtot}
\newcommand{\Immi}[2]{%
  \setlength{\lgtot}{0.5\linewidth}%
  \ifnum#1=1
\par 
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\lgtot}%
#2
 \end{minipage}%
\else
  %
\hspace*{-\decal}\begin{minipage}[t]{\lgtot}%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
 \colorbox{white}{\titreexo}#2
\end{minipage}%
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}%
\lipsum[12]
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}%
  \Immi{0}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{ex}

\Immi{1}{%
  \begin{ex}%
\lipsum[2]
  \end{ex}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `\Immi` you put `\par` right at the start which starts a new paragraph. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes. It must have `\par` command @plante. It can appear somewhere in my file, out side the `ex` environment.

Comment: Then how do you plan to resolve this if you **must** have `\par` inside `\Immi`? Maybe instead of that you want to alter the behavior of `\Immi` whenever you are in the `ex` environment?

Comment: One option is to make `ex` set a boolean variable (`\newif...`) and have `\Immi` check whether the variable is set. If yes: omit the `\par`, and if not set, keep the `\par`.  // to prevent unintended consequences: can there be two separate calls to `\immi` within the same `ex`?

Comment: @WillieWong I am trying to do that. But I can not check the condition.

Comment: Morever, the minipage is translated to left.

Comment: Is the answer OK for you?

Comment: @pascal974 It is alse meet trouble with left margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.
I suggest this.

```
   \documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641994/how-to-change-an-environment-in-its-body
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0pt
\newcounter{ex}
\newlength{\decal}
\setlength{\decal}{3em}%
\newcommand{\titreexo}{\parbox[t]{\decal}{\bfseries Ex \theex.}%
}

\newenvironment{ex}{%
\par\refstepcounter{ex}{\titreexo}%
}{\vspace{1ex}}

\newlength{\lgtot}
\newcommand{\Immi}[2]{%
  \setlength{\lgtot}{0.5\linewidth}%
  \ifnum#1=1
    \addtolength{\lgtot}{\decal}%
    %\addtolength{\lgtot}{3.5pt}% ????????????????
    \par 
  \fi
  %
\begin{minipage}[t]{\lgtot}%
#2
\end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}%
  Contents 1.
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}%
  \Immi{0}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{ex}

\Immi{1}{%
  \begin{ex}%
\lipsum[2]
  \end{ex}
}
\end{document}
```

EDIT2

A new version with your code.
With a boolean no need for a second parameter in the command.

```
            \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{ifthen}% pour la définition du booléen
    \parindent=0pt
    \newboolean{booleenEx}
    \setboolean{booleenEx}{false}
    \newcounter{ex}
    \newlength{\decal}
    \newcommand{\titreexo}{%
        \parbox[t]{\decal}{\bfseries Ex \theex.}%
    }
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \newenvironment{ex}
    {%
    \setboolean{booleenEx}{true}
    \settowidth{\decal}{\bfseries Ex \theex..}
    \par\refstepcounter{ex}{\titreexo}%
    }
    {
        \setboolean{booleenEx}{false}\vspace{1ex}
    }

    %\newlength{\lgtot}<-- No longer needed
    \newcommand{\Immi}[1]
    {%
    %\setlength{\lgtot}{0.5\linewidth}%<-- No longer needed
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{booleenEx}}
        {%
        \hspace*{-\decal}%<--- A good idea
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}%
            \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
            \colorbox{white}{\titreexo}#1
        \end{minipage}%
        }%
        {%
        \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}%
    #1
        \end{minipage}%
        }

    }%

    \begin{document}
    \begin{ex}%
        \lipsum[12]
    \end{ex}

    \begin{ex}%
        \Immi{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{ex}

    \Immi{%
        \begin{ex}%
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{ex}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it also has a large white space on left margin Sir.

Comment: I can not post long comment here.
From your sugguestion, I modify for my pupose. 
It work for me, but I think It can have better solution.

Comment: Thank you. In your code \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\colorbox{white}{\titreexo}#2 can be replaced by \titreexo#2 no?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works well. However, when the `ex` enviroment is the end of page, text `Ex. number` is repeated on two pages.

Comment: new version. With a boolean no need for a second parameter in the command. See the answer

Comment: Many thanks Sir!